# Custom Toolbar android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

i wish to create an toolbar like this one shown below :

[image]

the problem i am having is te get the half icon on the left extreme. how can i get that? i have been successfull with the othe parts of which code i am giving below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.app.InstHomeDir.NavigationView.InstaDrawer">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#da251c"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_toolbar_instadrawer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/logo2"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/call_toolbar_instadrawer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:src="@drawable/call_toolbar"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/insta_content_drawer" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: which icon you want on left side? actually i don't understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this it will definitely resolve your problem

add this line in your Toolbar

> app:contentInsetStart="0dp"

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#da251c"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >
```